# Обработка List внутри Map через Stream API

Tags: java, list, map, java-stream

Всем привет!
Есть задача получить новый список объектов из объектов внутри map за один проход через Stream API.

- Есть `Map<Boolean, List<User>>` in;
- Есть `class UserNew(User user, Boolean b)`;
- Нужно получить `List<UserNew> из in` (либо как промежуточный вариант, хотя бы `Map<User, Boolean>`).

Проблема в том, что как только из списков внутри map делаю stream, уже не могу вернуться к keySet().

Делал так:

```
List<UserNew> result=
   in.entrySet().stream()
      .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
      .map(user -> {
      return new UserNew(
      user,
      __вот здесь нужно получить key из map__);
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Важное условие сделать это за один проход.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обмануть судьбу))

```
List<UserNew> result = in.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(user->new UserNew(user, entry.getKey())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Все дело в этой несчастной скобке после Stream:( И ведь логично же, наверно, уже глаз замылился. Спасибо.